# SaveAs slected sheets (save as pdf with user prompting save to location)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to save selected sheets as a PDF, but I would like the user to prompt where the pdf should be saved to, hence I'm using a SaveAs code.
the following code only saves the first sheet ... please can you tell me how to amend the code so it saves only the selected sheets?

```
Sub saveas()

Sheets(Array("TITLE", "CONTENTS", "Units Shipped", "Discs Shipped", "AVG TAT NR", "AVG TAT RO", "DELIVERY PERFORMANCE")).Select

Dim v As Variant
v = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Sound Performance KPI For " & Sheets("TITLE").Range("A16").Value & " - " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy_hhmm") & ".pdf", "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

If VarType(v) = vbString Then
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=v, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being daft ... simply changed the 'activeworkbook' to 'activesheet'

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=v, _
```